# Android Parcelable List<String[]>

Tags: java, android, json, parcelable

I have a JSON and i wanted to put it into parcelable class so that i can pass its object from one activity to other. i have used Parcelable before several times. but this time i got confused with how to create the parcelable class with below JSON response.

Actually the confusion is with  `List<String[]>` arraylist of `String[]` how can i pass this.

```
[
    {
    puzzle_title: "Puzzle",
    grid_size: "8",
    data: [
    [
    "J",
    "J",
    "P",
    "Y",
    "B",
    "T",
    "P",
    "U"
    ],
    [
    "L",
    "W",
    "B",
    "I",
    "Q",
    "M",
    "S",
    "L"
    ],
    [
    "K",
    "Y",
    "Q",
    "L",
    "N",
    "A",
    "W",
    "D"
    ],
    [
    "Y",
    "E",
    "I",
    "G",
    "U",
    "G",
    "H",
    "V"
    ],
    [
    "B",
    "L",
    "A",
    "C",
    "K",
    "E",
    "I",
    "F"
    ],
    [
    "X",
    "L",
    "Q",
    "T",
    "B",
    "N",
    "T",
    "B"
    ],
    [
    "O",
    "O",
    "R",
    "E",
    "D",
    "T",
    "E",
    "W"
    ],
    [
    "H",
    "W",
    "B",
    "K",
    "H",
    "A",
    "F",
    "V"
    ]
    ],
    words: [
    "RED",
    "YELLOW",
    "BLUE",
    "BLACK",
    "WHITE",
    "MAGENTA"
    ]
    },
    {}
    ]
```

I have write my parcelable class like below..

```
    public class PuzzelSetter implements Parcelable {

    @SerializedName("puzzle_title")
    private String title;
    @SerializedName("grid_size")
    private int size;
    private List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    private List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public List<String[]> getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(List<String[]> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public List<String> getWords() {
        return words;
    }

    public void setWords(List<String> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public void setSize(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setData(ArrayList<String[]> data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

    public void setWords(ArrayList<String> words) {
        this.words = words;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(title);
        dest.writeInt(size);
        dest.writeList(data);
        dest.writeStringList(words);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<PuzzelSetter> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<PuzzelSetter>() {

        @Override
        public PuzzelSetter createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new PuzzelSetter(source);
        }

        @Override
        public PuzzelSetter[] newArray(int size) {
            return new PuzzelSetter[size];
        }
    };

    public PuzzelSetter(Parcel parcel) {
        title = parcel.readString();
        size = parcel.readInt();
        //data = parcel.readStringArray(val);
        parcel.readStringList(words);
    }

}
```

**Update:**

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeInt(size);        
    dest.writeStringList(words);
    dest.writeInt(data.size()); // write list size
    for (String[] letters : data) { 
        dest.writeStringArray(letters); //write each element
    }
}

public PuzzelSetter(Parcel parcel) {
    title = parcel.readString();
    size = parcel.readInt();        
    //List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    int size = parcel.readInt(); // read size
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String[] letters = parcel.createStringArray(); // read each element
        data.add(letters);
    }
    parcel.readStringList(words);
}
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write all list elements to parcel separately:

```
dest.writeInt(data.size()); // write list size
for (String[] letters : data) { 
    dest.writeStringArray(letters); //write each element
}
```

And how to read it:

```
List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();
int size = parcel.readInt(); // read size
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    String[] letters = parcel.createStringArray(); // read each element
    data.add(letters);
}
```

**UPD:**

In your case:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(title);
    dest.writeInt(size);        
    dest.writeStringList(words);
    dest.writeInt(data.size()); // write list size
    for (String[] letters : data) { 
        dest.writeStringArray(letters); //write each element
    }
}

public PuzzelSetter(Parcel parcel) {
    title = parcel.readString();
    size = parcel.readInt();        
    parcel.readStringList(words);
    int size = parcel.readInt(); // read size
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        String[] letters = parcel.createStringArray(); // read each element
        data.add(letters);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. i have implement it using your code, but my url is not working right now. we have some server issue. so i haven't tested it. as soon as i test the code i will let u know whether it is working or not.

Comment: its not working.. i think i am doing something wrong my List<String[]> and List<String> are getting interchanged. any idea.

Comment: Place `parcel.readStringList(words);` above `int size = parcel.readInt();`